# Matlab line plot: is it possible to set marker line width separately?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**Is there a way to set the marker line width separately in a Matlab plot?**

If we use `'LineWidth'`, it will change the width of both the marker edge and the line itself. We can plot marker and the line in two separate `plot` functions, however, there will be a problem in setting the legend.

Comment: You can pick and choose which lines should appear in the legend. If you plot the marker and lines separately, you can have only the marker in the legend, which looks rather nice IMO.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes, I can set`'HandleVisibility', 'off'` to have a single line in the legend (which I am currently using). But I am interested in knowing the possibility of having the 'perfect' legend

Comment: If I understand the MATLAB help correctly, it is not possible using only one plot: _Line width, specified as a positive value in points. If the line has markers, then the line width also affects the marker edges._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be possible, but it is undocumented.

`Line` objects have a hidden property `MarkerHandle` which references a `Marker` object representing the drawn markers; this object has its own `LineWidth` property. Once the markers have been drawn, the `Marker` object's `LineWidth` property affects the marker line width independently from the `LineWidth` property on the main `Line` object. This allows you to do:

```
hLine = plot(myData, 'Marker',myMarkerType, 'LineWidth',myMainLineWidth);
drawnow;
hLine.MarkerHandle.LineWidth = myMarkerLineWidth;
```

However this property *doesn't* seem to affect the line's entry in a legend. This, too, is accessible through undocumented properties though.

```
hLegend = legend;
drawnow;
lineEntry = findobj(hLegend.EntryContainer, 'Object',hLine);
entryMarker = findobj(lineEntry.Icon.Transform, 'Description','Icon Marker');
entryMarker.LineWidth = myMarkerLineWidth;
```

This works for me in MATLAB R2018b, but since it's not documented there are no guarantees the result will behave exactly as you expect. In particular, you might need to look out for your manual changes being overwritten automatically by other updates you make to your plot using documented features which cause the markers to be redrawn.

Comment: Thanks, @Will, But it gives me an error `Property assignment is not allowed when the object is empty.` my code is `hline=plot(xData,yData,'-.','Marker','O','MarkerSize',20, 'MarkerFaceColor',myFacecolor,'MarkerEdgeColor','k'); hline.MarkerHandle.LineWidth = 1;`. The datatip on `hline` shows as `handle to deleted Line`

Comment: Oops... I was testing line by line, but the objects involved are actually not created until the markers are finished drawing, so you have to force MATLAB to finish drawing before continuing using `drawnow` to ensure the objects are ready to use when running the code all at once. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Perfectly working! Thanks (I can only accept the answer and cannot vote yet - will definitely add a vote when I get sufficient reputation)